# script causing odd scaling behaviour on child object in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a small turret object and a target object that moves about my scene.

In the turret's script I make them aim at the object.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class indivMover : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject t1;
    public GameObject target;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        t1.transform.LookAt(target.transform);
    }
}
```

this worked fine until I parented many of the turrets to a larger object so I could move them around as one. Now they all distort as they point away from their starting position. Why is this happening?

Comment: Is the parent object scaled non-uniformly? Non-uniform scale, can add distortion when changing hierarchy.